# How can we query on a table that its table does not exists in database?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am new to Postgress and using Sequelize , on the tables in database we have 25 tables. in our codes we have so more that number as model.
my question is how are we able to query on that model that only exists in models but not database and everything is working smooth and find?
[image: tabels]
[image: models]

example , we do not have any user_companies among tables in database, but we have the model among codes and it is working fine. when i want to do some modification on the models it needs modification on tables but there is no table in database for that model.
how is this working? and how can i handle that?
thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps the 'model' is working with both tables, perhaps builds a query that joins tables and pulls data from query.

Comment: how is that possible? can you provide an example?